# How to make power bi visuals resize responsively on my site

Tags: html, powerbi

I am not the strongest programmer but I'm learning and trying to this project done.

So when I get the embedded code from Power Bi it gives it to me like this:

```
<iframe width="800" height="600"
    src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYzBiODViMzktYzlhNi00YzVmLWIwNDItMTczZmIyNzBhMzQwIiwidCI6IjUyOWQ1YzEyLWUwN2YtNGEwNi1hN2JhLTE2MGZiYjAxZDVkMyJ9"
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"> 
</iframe>
```

I then take that line of code and open the HTML Source Editor and put that in. I resized it o 350 by 350 so that I can fit 3 graphs beside each other. It looks fine until you make the window smaller or look at it from a small laptop. All 3 images overlap each other.

So How can i make it responsive with the size?

Answer (score 1):

This is Power BI code. You can't change the way it's rendered. The only option you have is to select the most appropriate size of the frame:

[image]

Then on your site you should provide space for the size you requested.

This is how `Publish to web` works. If you want to go deeper, you can try to embed individual tiles using Power BI Embedded, but this isn't trivial task and will require programming.